# JBoss maven plugin: deployment fails, dependencies not found

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I am porting our project from an ant-build to a maven-build. I used the jboss-javaee6-ear-webapp Archetype as a base.

So my setup also consists of a super-pom, an ear, ejb and war sub-module. I have also copied the jboss-as-maven-plugin config

(and tried it with 3 different versions of the plugin).

But the deployment still fails with:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] myProg Framework ................................... SUCCESS [  0.390 s]
[INFO] myProgEJB module .................................. SUCCESS [  3.848 s]
[INFO] myProgWeb module .................................. FAILURE [  0.051 s]
[INFO] myProgEAR module .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.711 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-11T13:49:48+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 49M/520M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myProg-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project at.mycomp:myProg-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact at.mycomp:myProg-ejb:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

mvn compile and mvn package work just fine and I can copy the EAR manually to my jboss deployment folder.

In the super-pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.7.Final</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In the ear-pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <port>9993</port>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: you'd need to provide a lot more context in terms of poms and other configuration xmls about what you are doing. If you do `mvn clean package` and deploy the resulting .ear manually, does that work?

Comment: I made a mistake in my original post. I meant "mvn package" not "deploy". I can successfully run clean, compile, package etc. and as written in my post, I can copy the EAR file manually. It doesn't successfully deploy, but that's another story and not expected at the moment.
I'm simply wondering why "mvn package" CAN resolve the deps and build a jar, war and ear, while the plugin can't.

Comment: if you're using wildfly (since you added the tag, though I don't see it mentioned), any particular reason you're not using [wildfly-maven-plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/)?

Comment: No, i added it because I thought no one was looking for jboss anymore :) But I've resolved the issue already. See answer below

Comment: Yes I noticed - trying to clean up this question so it would be more useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JBoss Archetype adds a dependency to the EJB part into the WEB part's pom

```
<!-- Dependency on the EJB module so we can use it's services if needed -->
```

The plugin can't find the EJB's POM though. I figured that out, by looking at the error message and commenting the dependency out. It then fails for the EAR part, because it can't find the dependencies on the sub-modules.

I just had to run `mvn install`, so the artefacts would be installed in the local repo.

It's the same issue and solution for the maven dependency:analyze plugin goal.

Comment: I found it very frustrating to have to install all my modules just to get better dependency information. The other horrible alternative is to classify all EJBs are JARs ... but that just leads to other issues with your EJB plugins etc.